# Sending String and int from MainActivity to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

Hey i am trying to send a string and an int from my MainActivity to my BroadcastReceiver. I get the String and int from my main_activity.xml linked to my MainActivity. Now i want to send them to my BroadcastReceiver.

Here is the code i used in MainActivity

```
MyBroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

I invoke the Receiver everytime there is a change in the battery level so i dont want to use a normal intent.

how do i send String and int variables from my MainActivity to MyBroadcastReceiver.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you filter *Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED*, so cannot send variables from activity to receiver. Action fires its intent and this intent has extra values in it. You can find keys from [here](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.4/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/BatteryManager.java)

Comment: so is there any work around for sending a string and an int ?

Comment: you can set a custom action and sendBroadcast(intent) will work where you set your extra values